# List the Max(difference ) of 2 column values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to calculate the Max of difference of 2 column values, and then group them by a common category (Symbol in this case).

```
Symbol  mydate      mytime          myopen  High    Low     myclose
ZEEL    2019-07-29   09:15:00.000   401.1   402.05  400.25  402.05
ZEEL    2019-07-29   09:17:00.000   401.6   402     398.6   400.7
ZEEL    2019-07-29   09:19:47.000   400     400     400     400
YESBANK 2019-07-29   09:15:00.000   95.8    96.05   94.6    95.25
YESBANK 2019-07-29   09:17:00.000   95.2    95.2    94.45   94.45
YESBANK 2019-07-29   09:19:46.000   93.8    93.8    93.8    93.8
WONDI   2019-07-29  09:15:00.000    258.8   258.8   258.75  258.75
```

(>12000  records like the above)

I would like to find the highest difference of High - Low values grouped by Symbol.

So I tried:

```
select symbol, (high-low)  as Diff from dcTbl_29072019 
where mytime>='15:01:35.000' 
order by symbol
```

I got:

```
symbol  Diff
AARTIIND    1.34999999999991
AARTIIND    0
ACC 1.25
```

I Now need to group the Above output Based on the Symbol
adding a Line with "group by symbol" returned an error.

TO be clear, my desired output is:

```
symbol  Diff
AARTIIND    1.34999999999991
ACC 1.25 ... (and So On).
```

TIA

Answer (score 2):

One way using a grouped subquery:

```sql
select  symbol, (high - low) as diff
from (
    select  symbol, max(high) as high, min(low) as low
    from dcTbl_29072019
    where mytime >= '15:01:35.000'
    group by symbol
) gr
order by symbol
```

Or, just doing it in one go:

```sql
select  symbol, max(high) - min(low) as diff
from dcTbl_29072019
where mytime >= '15:01:35.000'
group by symbol
order by symbol
```

Comment: Think I'd stick with the 'one-go' method

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, (t.high - t.low) as Diff
from dcTbl_29072019 t
where t.mytime >= '15:01:35.000' and
      (t.high - t.low) = (select max(t2.high - t2.low)
                          from dcTbl_29072019 t2
                          where t2.symbol = t.symbol and
                                t2.mytime >= '15:01:35.000'
                         )
order by symbol
```

Comment: Thanks gordon, will try this in the next 2-3 Hours from Now.